# Facing issue while download file from sharepoint in node.js using sp-download npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharepoint

I am using sp-download to download file from sharepoint in node js. I am executing the below code -

```
const Download = require('sp-download').Download;
    let authContext = await spauth.getAuth(CONFIG.SHAREPOINT.SITES_LINK, {
        username: CONFIG.SHAREPOINT.CREDS.USERNAME,
        password: CONFIG.SHAREPOINT.CREDS.PASSWORD
    });
    const download = new Download(authContext);
    let filePathToDownload = CONFIG.SHAREPOINT.SITES_LINK + 'sharePointFile File Path';
    let saveToPath = 'localFile Path';
    download.downloadFile(filePathToDownload, saveToPath)
    .then((savedToPath) => {
        return true;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error", error);
        return false;
    });
```

But code will result below error -
"**Error while resolving authentication class**"

Any one have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with it as well and ended up debbuging *node_modules/node-sp-auth/lib/src/auth/AuthResolverFactory.js* where the error comes from.

Using Office 365 login and pass it should be enough to set authContext as simple object.

```
const username = CONFIG.SHAREPOINT.CREDS.USERNAME;
const password = CONFIG.SHAREPOINT.CREDS.PASSWORD;
const download = new Download({username, password});
```

In your case.